# Dismiss iPhone number pad when a read only UITextView is touched

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitextview

In my simple iPhone app, I have a UITextField for entering text and UITextView for results. The UITextField uses a number pad since only numbers are allowed. The UITextView is read only but has user interaction enabled. The reason for this is that I want a user to be able to do copy and paste but not changing the result. It is well known that number pad doesn't have a "go" button. So I do `resignFirstResponder() in touchesBegan` and it works as long as I touch outside of the Text View Area. How do I dismiss the keyboard (number pad) even when the inside  of the UITextView is touched?

Comment: Side note - some users may be using an external keyboard so make sure you are properly validating user input into the text field since such users will be able to type letters and other symbols.

Comment: I think this might be what your looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782664/uitextfield-functionality-with-no-keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You could add a gesture recognizer to the UITextView. Untested code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[self.textView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[tap release]; // not necessary or allowed under ARC
```

and then the handler:

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap
{
    // resign first responder and whatever else you need to do
}
```

You may need to disable the gesture recognizer when you don’t need it, in case it interferes with text selection in the read-only `UITextView`.